# unable to convert my maven to eclipse

Tags: maven-3

Please, I am new to maven and trying to build my first maven project. So, here are a few things I did:

from my command line into a directory called MavenProject I created:
mvn archetype:generate
and then choose a number to apply number, I entered 15 then;
Choose com.dyuproject.protostuff.archetype:basic-webapp version:
I chose version 1.0.7
 groupId: com.henry
 artifactId: HibernateTest
 and the rest, I just entered..

and the project was created but then I typed in mvn eclipse:eclipse, I got an error that there was no pom.xml file even though I can see there is one in my mavenProject. so, I changed into the HibernateTest directory and in that directory, I tried the mvn eclipse:eclipse command again but this time, it gave the eorror:

```
Plugin com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-maven-plugin:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact 
com.dyuproject.protostuff:protostuff-maven-plugin:pom:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

I tried to solve this by going to mvnrepository.com and found the protostuff maven and added the dependencies but still couldn't solve it. here is my pom.xml file:

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLS$
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_$
    <parent>
    <artifactId>Hibernate</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.henry</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
     </parent>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.henry</groupId>
       <artifactId>Hibernate-model</artifactId>
       <name>Hibernate :: model</name>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>

       <build>
      <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>protostuff-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${protostuff.version}</version>
    <configuration>
    <protoModules>
        <protoModule>
          <source>src/main/resources/com/henry/model/model.proto</source>
          <outputDir>src/main/java</outputDir>
          <output>java_bean</output>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <options>
            <property>
              <name>generate_field_map</name>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>separate_schema</name>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>builder_pattern</name>
            </property>
            <property>
              <name>generate_helper_methods</name>
            </property>
          </options>
        </protoModule>
        </protoModules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
 </build>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>protostuff-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>protostuff-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
   <artifactId>protostuff-codegen</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
   <artifactId>protostuff-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>protostuff-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
   <artifactId>protostuff-codegen</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.dyuproject.protostuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>protostuff-compiler</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.7</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>

 </project>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Sorry am a newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

First try to build the project on the command line: `mvn install`. That should succeed.

But it looks like it won't, as it is looking for a SNAPSHOT dependency version of `${protostuff.version}`. When I [look](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.dyuproject.protostuff%22%20AND%20a%3A%22protostuff-maven-plugin%22) in the Maven central repository, there's really only release versions (as it should be). Somehow you have to fix that, probably in your parent project.

The POM file should be in the root of the project and called `pom.xml`. Where you find the POM file called `pom.xml` is the root of the project :)

Only use `eclipse:eclipse` as a last resort. If you have free choice of Eclipse, and you have no wizardry in your Maven projects, you should be able to use the [m2e (m2eclipse) Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).

That's an Eclipse plugin, not a Maven plugin, so no additional steps are needed on the command line. Just go into Eclipse, make sure the m2e plugin is [installed](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/). Then import your project (Import, "Existing Maven Projects").

All the files that Eclipse needs for its own bookkeeping should be created upon import and be based on the POM file. I.e. `.classpath`, `.project` and `.settings` (folder). If you have any of those prior to importing into Eclipse, you may be better off removing them (they may be remnants of your `eclipse:eclipse` attempts.